# How can I improve my button which uses a Html.ActionLink inside a styled div

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

So far I have a div which takes Bootstrap button styling and it has a Html.ActionLink within the div:

```
<div class="btn btn-success">
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</div>
```

This displays the correct green 'success' Bootstrap button and it has text 'Create New' with a link to the 'Create' Action.

However the problem is that the color remains dark blue as a result of the `a{}` tag css, but it should be white as a result of the btn-success Bootstrap button class.

Also I can only click the text as a link. The entire button is not clickable as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

This styles your a tag as a bootstrap button

Comment: Thanks for that Bolt19! :D

Answer (score 1):

in you css you should style:

```
.btn-success a{display:block;color:#fff;}
```

the display block would cause the a to fill the entire button, the color would be the color of the link.

Comment: Thank you for that Omer! :)